# C# script inside ssis package

Tags: sql-server

I have a C# script inside ssis package that connect to print servers to get all print queues information from each server. The code is as follow

```
string[] serverslist = new string[]{"\\\\server1",...}
foreach(string servername in serverslist)
{
   `myPrintServer = new System.Printing.PrintServer(servername);
    PrintQueues = myPrintServer.GetPrintQueues(); --- line 
`}
```

line 1 failed when run from sql server agent, but run fine in bids
the error is:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Printing.PrintServerException: An exception occurred while creating the PrintServer object. Win32 error: The printer name is invalid

Comment: Hm... the ` right before the "myPrintServer" is really in the code and the code fails? Did you outout the servername in the loop? Would be interesting to know, what the loop produces... maybe there are empty strings or something?

Comment: thanks for reply. For some strange reason it started working.